# geocoding Flutter, can't import 'package:geocoding/geocoding.dart'

Tags: android, flutter, dart, geolocation, geocoding

I'm using geolocator: ^7.7.0 to get longitude and latitude coordinates so that way I can get the adress with placemarkFromCoordinates().

Everything is going well:

```
Position position = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high);
print('Latitude: ${position.latitude}, Longitude: ${position.longitude}');
```

As you can see I'm able to get longitude and latitude coordinates. The problem is that when I try to import 'package:geocoding/geocoding.dart' to use placemarkFromCoordinates() the following error occurs:

```
Target of URI doesn't exist: 'package:geocoding/geocoding.dart'. Try creating the file referenced by the URI, or Try using a URI for a file that does exist. (darturi_does_not_exist)
```

I already tried to flutter clean and fluter build apk and the following come:

```
Note: C:\REMSYSTEMFIRE-FIXOS\Componentes\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\geocoding-2.0.1\android\src\main\java\com\baseflow\geocoding\Geding\GeocodingPlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
```

My pubspec.yaml dependencies has both:

```
geolocator: ^7.7.0
geocoding: ^2.0.1
```

My AndroidManifest.xml permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

build.gradle:

```
compileSdkVersion 31
minSdkVersion 21
targetSdkVersion 30
```

gradle.properties:

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

And all others android. dependencies was replaced to their AndroidX counterparts.

Please, is that someone that know the reason of that problem?

Thank's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you declare the geolocator: ^7.7.0, geocoding: ^2.0.1 correctly. and run `flutter packages get`

Also Few Extra steps :

1. Flutter Clean
2. Close Android Studio or Vs Code
3. Remove Build Folder
4. Remove .idea Folder
5. Finger Crossed!

Comment: Well, apparently turning the computer off and on again, crossing my fingers, worked. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: I'm glad to hear that!